# Is it safe to use UTF-8 characters (like ✖) on my web-page?

Tags: html, utf-8, fonts

I would like to use the UTF-8 character ✖ on my site but I am not sure if this will be supported cross browser.

I am worried that:

a) Users will not have access to a font containing that character

b) IE will not find the character even if the user has a font that could display it.   I am worried about this because of this info:

> By the specifications, browsers should display a character if there is any font in the system that contains it. If the fonts specified by the author (in CSS font-family settings or, rarely these days, using font markup in HTML) do not contain the character, browsers are sup­posed to use fallback fonts. The same applies if no fonts are specified by the author; brows­ers should use primarily their default fonts, using alternate fonts for any character not covered by the primary font.
>
> In practice, things don’t always work that way. Especially IE is notorious for its failures in this respect. It often fails to display a character, even though it could do that if it used all the fonts in the system. If a browser cannot render a character, it may show a small rectangle, possibly containing a question mark, ?, or some similar indicator. Here’s a quick test (char­ac­ter U+0840, which is probably not supported by any font on your computer): ࡀ.

[Source](http://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/html/characters.html).

c) Other issues that I have though of.

There is a resource called [Unify](http://unicode.johnholtripley.co.uk/), that will show what devices the character is supported on but it currently (Sept 14, 2015) only suport 107 characters.

---

So to summarize, the question is: How can I determine if it is safe to use a utf-8 special character on my site?  Is it safe to use ✖ specifically on my site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always *safe* - your user's computers won't suddenly burst into flame.

From a technical perspective, your best bet is to use a web font that has support for every Unicode character you want to use. That is not a catch-all (the user might have web fonts disabled or is using a command line browser, etc...), but it should support the vast majority of computers.

From there I would apply common sense. If the displaying of a character is absolutely crucial and lives depend on it, try to not use Unicode. Otherwise I'd say 'go ahead'.

Answer (score 2):

This is as much a UX question as it is a technical one, so I will mention both.

As a comparison, on my IE11 browser, it looks like this: [image], but on my Firefox 31.8, it looks like this: [image]. A good user experience is generally associated with consistency, and this approach is not very portable. So from a UX perspective, this is not a great solution.

I would say using a tiny *.gif or *.bmp, or even *.png if you need transparency, is a better solution. Even better yet, go with *.svg so scaling will not be an issue. From a technical aspect, the overhead of something that small is generally insignificant.

Comment: Or, fairly obviously, make sure to use a webfont that has the character, so that it looks the same for everyone (especially since IE has had supported web fonts since IE4)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - Hi Mike, I didn't think about using a webfont.  If you want to create answer saying more or less 'if you webfont has it, it will work' then I will accept that.  If/when you answer, please add a comment with me flagged (so I get a notification).

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude Actually, the most [popular answer by orlp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32572474/2066079) you were given does suggest this - "your best bet is to use a web font that has support" However, he does go on to say that  this isn't a perfect solution because "the user might have web fonts disabled or is using a command line browser, etc..."

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude added. Also, people who have webfonts disabled are the vast minority of users: that's like turning off page CSS and using your own instead (also done by some poeople, but it's an incredibly small segment of web users).

Answer (score 1):

The only problem you can face is that exotic symbols are not implemented in many fonts, so the user can see a dummy character (e.g. square) instead of this. I personally like to use svg symbols for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to use a web font with those icons in it (although probably a subset version of, so that it's less and 1 kb and doesn't weight down your pages).